# The member is not recognized or is not accessible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF I have

```
public class AttachedColumnBehavior
{        


    public static readonly DependencyProperty MappedValuesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MappedValues",
            typeof(MappedValueCollection),
            typeof(AttachedColumnBehavior),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnMappedValuesPropertyChanged));

}

   public static MappedValueCollection GetMappedValues(DependencyObject dataGrid)
    {
        return (MappedValueCollection)dataGrid.GetValue(MappedValuesProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMappedValues(DependencyObject dataGrid, MappedValueCollection value)
    {
        dataGrid.SetValue(MappedValuesProperty, value);
    }
```

and in my Xaml I have

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectoin}" x:Name="myGrid" 

                  loc:AttachedColumnBehavior.MappedValues="{Binding MyCollectionValues}"                      
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
```

But I am getting `The Member MappedValues is not recognized or is not acessible` error.

Comment: Works for me. Did you try to rebuild all?

Comment: I did..But it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Do you get that message only in designer (but the application still runs), or is it a compiler error?

Comment: Only in compiler...but the application still runs

Comment: You mean in designer. Restart Visual Studio.